# Elasticsearch return wrong sum in aggregration while value is large

Tags: elasticsearch

I have inserted 1 record with large amount in elastic search. The value is 99999999999

I have used below query and it return sum but value is wrong. It return 9.9999997952E10 how can I get accurate data?

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "subscribercompanyid": 40408
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "invoicedetails": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "invoicedetails"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "Childe": {
                    "sum": {
                        "field" : "invoicedetails.valueinnumeric"

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Response

```
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "invoicedetails": {
      "doc_count": 1,
      "Childe": {
        "value": 9.9999997952E10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the data type of `invoicedetails.valueinnumeric`?

Comment: Its data type is float.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a `double` instead of a `float` then it's going to work as you expect:

```
PUT test 
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "total": {
          "type": "float"
        },
        "total2": {
          "type": "double"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT test/doc/1
{
  "total": 99999999999,
  "total2": 99999999999
}

POST test/_search 
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "total": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "total"
      }
    },
    "total2": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "total2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Results =>

```
{
  "aggregations" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 9.9999997952E10
    },
    "total2" : {
      "value" : 9.9999999999E10
    }
  }
}
```